# Routing values per index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The system has big amount of companies. Companies have users, users have folders with files. We want to build search by file/folder metadata and would like to use ElasticSearch for this.

Our intention is to use root folder id as a sharding key because an average user has about 10 root folders.

Some companies are much bigger than others in number of files and folders. And we would like to optimize queries coming into ElasticSearch so extract these companies into separate indexes. The issue is that some users have folders in numerous companies so query request should go into numerous indexes.

Let say user from a small company has folder 1 (owned by small company) and 2 (owned by huge company). So request should go into *small_companies_index* and *huge_company_A_index*. Alias *all_companies* is created with *small_companies_index* and *huge_company_A* indexes. 
Actual request will look like

```
GET /all_companies_alias/_search?routing=1,2
```

As a result ES will go into *huge_company_A_index* and request shards calculated by values [1,2] and does the same in *small_companies_index*

Is there a way to tell ES that routing key 1 corresponds to *small_companies_index* only and 2 to *huge_company_A_index* so don't make unnecessary shards requests?

Is there any other approach to solve the problem?

Comment: Are users generally searching all their folders at once, or often searching within a folder? If users typically search all their folders at once, then why not use the user as the sharding key instead of the folder?

Comment: Users are searching all folders at once typically, however users have shared folders usually so this approach will not be really good